# Android DBflow : define entity schema name

Tags: java, android, android-room, greendao, dbflow

For my application, I'm using DBflow ORM. Nice and easy, a database is created and filled with my empty tables.

**My concern is, how do you define in DBflow, to which schema (database) an entity belongs?**

Example: dbo.[Dictionary]

DBfLow **@Table** annotation provides some methods, but nothing which can define a schema name.

I did a research and found out that GreenDAO **@Entity** annotation provides a parameter **schema = "schema_name"**.

http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/modelling-entities/

Didn't find anything in Room.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting an example from [link](https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2015/02/go-dbflow-fastest-android-orm-database-library/)

```
@Table(databaseName = AppDatabase.NAME)
public class TestModel1 extends BaseModel {
    @Column(columnType = Column.PRIMARY_KEY)
    public
    String name;
}
```

`databaseName` should do.